# Populate method not populating my comment array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

this is my PostSchema creation in mongoose, I've made a reference to the users table in both my post as well as the comment.

```
 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  comment: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

What I was trying to do was have the post update the user element on ref, when I am calling it, to provide the user id and the name.

```
    const posts = await Post.find().populate('user', 'name');
```

Which worked with this, but it didn't do the same for each of the users ref in the comment. Did I do something wrong?

Edit:

```
const newComment = {
        user: user._id,
        text: req.body.text,
      };
      post.comment.unshift(newComment);
      await post.save();
```

This is the code for the comment addition, user._id is the objectId of the current loggedin user.

I even tried making

```
        user: user._id,
```

to

```
user: req.user.id,


const newPost = new Post({
        text: req.body.text,
        title: req.body.title,
        user: req.user.id,
      });

      await newPost.save();
```

This is the code for the newPost, again req.user.id is the ID of the current loggedin in.

**Edit:**

this is user schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem a while back but I thought I would just update it here.

```
const posts = await Post.find().populate({select:"comments":populate:{path:'users'}});
```

select picks the path from the schema, then we can nest another populate path to specify nested options.

Answer (score 0):

Please see how the populate can be use

```js
let articles = await Product.find({ _id: { $in: items } })
    .populate("brand")
    .populate("wood")
    .exec();
Story.
  find().
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'name' }).
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
// The above is equivalent to:
Story.find().populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
```

d

Comment: It didn't work for me, I even tried doing what was suggested for multilevel population on mongoose docs.

Comment: Can you share the User Schema

Comment: i have added the Users Schema to the post @Adepitan Oriyomi

Comment: When Exporting your schema it should be singular 
use module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); instead

 user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by that. I added in that code to create a reference to the users collection to populate the user field with the object Id from the user collection

Comment: module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema); this is your current export declaration ,  use this module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); instead and see the changes in the database document , and also update the referencing